# How can I access the parent row from dataimporthandler

Tags: java, solr, dataimporthandler, transformer-model

I want to make a custom transformer for dataimporthandler. I want to access the row of the parent entity. How can I do that. Is it possible?

```
  @Override
  public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context) {

    LOG.info("##gyk: row: {}",row);

    //******What to do here? ********
    LOG.info("##gyk: PARENT-ROW: {}", ????);


    return row;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

My current workaround is to use session variables

```
  @Override
  public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context) {

    if (context.isRootEntity()) {

      Object tmp = row.get("Keywords");
      if (tmp == null) return row;

      String[] kwArray = tmp.toString().split(",");

      HashSet<String> kwSet = new HashSet<String>(64);

      for (String kw : kwArray) {
        kwSet.add(kw.trim().toLowerCase());
      }
      LOG.info("##gyk: root entity kw: {}",kwSet);

      context.setSessionAttribute("company-keywords-set", kwSet, "document");

    } else {
      LOG.info("##gyk: row: {}",row);

      HashSet<String> companyKeywordSet = (HashSet<String>)context
          .getParentContext().getParentContext()
          .getSessionAttribute("company-keywords-set", "document");

      if (companyKeywordSet != null) {
        LOG.info("##gyk: keywords from parent: {}", companyKeywordSet);
      }

    }

    return row;
  }
```

**Update**

When I try to log this `context.getParentContext().getParentContext().getAllEntityFields()`, I get the following:
`[{multiValued=false, toWrite=true, indexed=true, name=id, column=FIR_NR, boost=1.0, defaultValue=null, stored=true, type=string}, {multiValued=false, toWrite=true, indexed=true, name=fir_name, column=FIR_NAME, boost=1.0, defaultValue=null, stored=true, type=text_general}]`

These are just the field  definitions for that entity.

Comment: getParentContext & getAllEntityFields() doesn't return the value ??

Comment: I don't know I'll try :)